# Python Openpyxl: Changing sheet names and keeping formulas intact

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have an Excel file template with various sheets, containing formulas that reference each other. Now, I was trying to modify the name of some of those sheets using:

```
import openpyxl
Workbook= openpyxl.load_workbook('/path/to/file')
worksheet = Workbook.get_sheet_by_name('SomeName')
Workbook.active = worksheet
worksheet.title = 'SomeOtherName'
Workbook.save('/path/to/anotherFile')
Workbook.close()
```

Unfortunately, and as I expected, the formulas that referred to the sheet 'SomeName' now show a broken reference. Is there any way to ensure the title update propagates to all the sheets.

Comment: No that is not possible. You can use the tokeniser to edit references, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, that's what I expected unfortunately. Though wanted to ask, what is the tokeniser?